# Exception specification in ˋtypedefˋ completely forbidden or only at toplevel?

Tags: c++, c++14, typedef, exception-specification

In C++14 Sec 15.4;2 it is stated, that ... An exception-specification shall not appear in a typedef declaration or alias-declaration.

That means the following is forbidden:

```
typedef void (*fn)(int) noexcept;
```

But does the the wording *shall not appear* mean the token `noexcept` cannot appear anywhere in a typedef declaration?

For instance are these both are forbidden as well?

```
typedef void (*fn1)(void (*)(int) noexcept);
typedef decltype(std::declval<void (*)(int)noexcept>()) fn2;
```

These both try to define a type `fn1` and `fn2` being able to point to a function that takes a pointer to a function taking an `int` and returning nothing while promising to never throw an exception.

So in my examples the exception-specification is not applied to the toplevel type `fn1` resp. `fn2` that are introduced by `typedef` but to the parameters these function may receive.

So should I take 15.4;2 verbatim and therefore my both examples are invalid? Or is only application to a type-definition forbidden and my examples are correct?

Comment: You refer to C++14 but tagged C++11. In the interests of being precise, which do you want?

Comment: I refer to C++14. Sorry for tagging it with C++11, it slips thru my fingers. Thanks for mention it!

Answer (score 6):

It's the whole thing.

Quoting the full wording of `[except.spec]/p2` from C++11 and C++14:

> An *exception-specification* shall appear only on a function declarator for a function type, pointer to function type, reference to function type, or pointer to member function type that is the top-level type of a declaration or definition, or on such a type appearing as a parameter or return type in a function declarator. An *exception-specification* shall not appear in a typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*.

Perhaps it's not completely clear, but I think it's sufficiently so: you can use an exception specification on a function declaration, including in a parameter or return type on a function declaration … but not in an alias declaration.

This wording has been completely removed in C++17; [`noexcept` is part of the type system now](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html).

Comment: FWIW, the paragraph was removed by [P0012R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html)

Comment: Thank you both for your help!